# How can I load much data from chrome.storage.local into a JQuery Datatable fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, datatables

Right now it takes about 80 seconds for my JQuery Datatable to load. The data is loaded from chrome.storage.local, edited a bit and then the datatable is created with

```
$('#matches').DataTable({
    data: matches,
    columns: [
        { "data": "c1", title: "Character 1" },
        { "data": "c2", title: "Character 2" },
        { "data": "w",  title: "Winner" },
        { "data": "sn", title: "Strategy" },
        { "data": "pw", title: "Prediction"},
        { "data": "t", title: "Tier" },
        { "data": "m", title: "Mode" },
        { "data": "o",  title: "Odds" },
        { "data": "ts", title: "Time" },
        { "data": "cf", title: "Crowd favor" },
        { "data": "if", title: "Illum favor" },
        { "data": "dt", title: "Date"}
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'date-eu', targets: 11 },
        { type: 'odds', targets: 7},
        { searchable: false, targets: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    ],
    lengthMenu: [ 15, 25, 50, 100 ],
    initComplete: function(settings, json) {
        $("#loading").hide();
    },
    createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
        $('td', row).eq(data.w).addClass('highlight');
    },
    deferRender: true,
});
```

where matches is an array of objects.

deferRender does not work since the data is not loaded with ajax. What is my best approach to make it work? Write the data as JSON into a temporary file and then use that as data source?

Comment: I would be careful about putting a large amount of data into chrome.storage: `chrome.storage is not a big truck. It's a series of tubes. And if you don't understand, those tubes can be filled, and if they are filled when you put your message in, it gets in line, and it's going to be delayed by anyone that puts into that tube enormous amounts of material.` -From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local This could be greatly contributing to the slowness of your methods.

Comment: @dYale Loading and processing the data from chrome.storage.local takes less than 2 seconds, processing it with the jQuery datatable takes 78 seconds.

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: Option `deferRender` work for Ajax **AND** JavaScript data source, so it's good to have it enabled.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com about 80k records.

Comment: Consider switching to server-side processing mode and Ajax sourced data if that is possible, see [Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/) for more information.